# Javascript quotes loop - jump to the first after finishing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problems with the script, because once all child elements are looped through I can't get back to the first element.

https://jsfiddle.net/pad5bp0o/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var length = $("#tips li").length;
  var old = 0;

  function show() {
    var news = getRan();
    $("#tips li").hide();
    $("#tips li:nth-child(" + news + ")").fadeIn("fast");
    old++;
  };

  function getRan() {
    var news = old + 1;
    if (news < length) {
      return news;
    } else {
      var news = 0 + 1;
      return news;
      old++;
    }
  };

  show();
  $("#something").html(length);
  setInterval(show, 1000);

});
```

```css
#tips,
#tips li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tips {
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
}

#tips li {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: none;
  /* hide the items at first only */
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tips">
  <li>... if you want to become a better coder you need to eat your vegetables?</li>
  <li>... it takes more time to code a web page then to make a pizza?</li>
  <li>... you should validate your code?</li>
  <li>... jQuery is your friend? For real!</li>
  <li>... no matter what some people claim, you can't learn CSS in 3 hours?</li>
</ul>
<div id="something"></div>
```

Comment: Do you need https://jsfiddle.net/vLevph82/

Comment: Is the idea to show all in a random fashion or just show all one by one? You need to reset old in any case

Comment: Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/pad5bp0o/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset `old` variable once you reach the last element.

```
function getRan() {
    var news = old + 1;
    if (news <= length) {
        return news;
    }

    news = 1;
    old = 0;
    return news;
};
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vLevph82/)

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. Also had to change this: news <= length

Answer (score 1):

Reset the variable(`old`) to initial value(`1`) once limit(`5`) is reached.

You can also simplify the function like below. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/pad5bp0o/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var length = $("#tips li").length;
  var old = 1;

  function show() {
    $("#tips li").hide();
    $("#tips li:nth-child(" + old + ")").fadeIn("fast");
    if (old == length) {
      old = 1;
    } else {
      old++;
    }
  };

  show();
  $("#something").html(length);
  setInterval(show, 1000);

});
```

```css
#tips,
#tips li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#tips {
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
}
#tips li {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: none;
  /* hide the items at first only */
}
.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tips">
  <li>1. ... if you want to become a better coder you need to eat your vegetables?</li>
  <li>2. ... it takes more time to code a web page then to make a pizza?</li>
  <li>3. ... you should validate your code?</li>
  <li>4. ... jQuery is your friend? For real!</li>
  <li>5. ... no matter what some people claim, you can't learn CSS in 3 hours?</li>
</ul>
<div id="something"></div>
```